# Check Collision function is matching on 2 objects in same location

Tags: javascript

Full code [here](https://github.com/3noki/udacity_front_end_web_developer/tree/master/project_3_frogger_style_arcade_game)

I've noticed if there are two bugs in the same location and the player collides, it counts two deaths as it's technically colliding with two different objects, How can I change this to check collision 1 at a time, or only count 1 death?

```
checkCollision(playerl,playerr) {
  //check collision for each bug
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var thisEnemy = allEnemies[i];
        if (
           thisEnemy.leftLimit < player.rightLimit &&
           thisEnemy.rightLimit > player.leftLimit &&
           thisEnemy.upperLimit > player.lowerLimit &&
           thisEnemy.lowerLimit < player.upperLimit) {
           console.log("collision");
           //console.log(player.lowerLimit, player.upperLimit, thisEnemy.lowerLimit, thisEnemy.upperLimit)
          player.loseLife();
       }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a setTimeout to implement a short period of invincibility after dying once?

```
//somewhere in your code
var dying = false;

checkCollision(playerl,playerr) {
  //check collision for each bug
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var thisEnemy = allEnemies[i];
        if (
            thisEnemy.leftLimit < player.rightLimit &&
            thisEnemy.rightLimit > player.leftLimit &&
            thisEnemy.upperLimit > player.lowerLimit &&
            thisEnemy.lowerLimit < player.upperLimit &&
            dying==false) {

            console.log("collision");
            dying=true; // dying is true, so we wont end up in this block again
            setTimeout(function(){
                dying=false; //after 500 milliseconds we set dying to false so our player has the ability to die again!
            },500);
            player.loseLife();
       }
    }
};
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I was trying to add a setTimeout else where without success, this works great. I see the timeout sets dying back to false after 500 milliseconds, enough for reset or gameover functions to run. Thanks!